# PnP Modern Search v4 web part is not working. Unable to filter based on the content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-search-webparts

I have added the PnP Modern Search v4 web part inside our SharePoint Online tenant from this url @ https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/releases/tag/4.4.1 .

Then i tried to show items from different site collections, where those items share a content type, as follow:-

[image]

and the following refiner:-

[image]

but i did not get any results inside the web part.. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Those are just refinement filters. you need to make your query string like this site:"https://site.sharepoint.com/" (contenttype:Site) (contenttype:List) (contenttype:Library)